# Why res.redirect doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I make an http.post request from Angular to an  api from backend.After post i make a redirect to another page.Redirect doesn't work..I want to make redirect from backend.Does anyone another method to redirect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect a redirect to work in the context of an ajax request??

The server is responding a 3XX response in the context of your ajax request, so your application has the burden of how to handle that response.

Your application can handle the redirect by assigning `window.location` if a redirect is applicable.